# How to hide the AVPlayer screen in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoapods

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(playMethod)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Play" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor purpleColor] 
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)playMethod {
    controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(15,50,345,300);
    controller.player = player;
    controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(backMethod)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, 0.0, 160.0, 40.0); // set your own position
    [controller.view addSubview:button1];
    [player pause];
    [player play];


}

-(void)backMethod
{
    controller.view.hidden=YES;
    [player pause];
}
```

I am trying to play an RTMP URL in AVPlayer and it works fine, but the problem is, I created a back button on the player itself but when I call its method (backMethod) nothing happens.  I want, When I click on the back button it should hide that screen (player screen )and play button screen should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put you player view inside a subview of your viewController's view.

And hide your subview rather than hiding the PlayerViewController's view because it's managed by the PlayerViewController's itself.

Answer (score 0):

You added   `button1`     to  `AVPlayerViewController.View`

Here :

```
[controller.view addSubview:button1];
```

So your Button **will not receive any touch events**
Just try to add to your `self.view` and  and remove back Button when hide it

Like That:

```
- (void)playMethod {
    controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:controller];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];

    controller.view.frame = CGRectMake(15,50,345,300);
    controller.player = player;
    controller.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    player.closedCaptionDisplayEnabled = NO;

    UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button1 addTarget:self
                action:@selector(backMethod)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button1 setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button1.frame = CGRectMake(50.0, CGRectGetMinY(self.controller.view.frame)+10, 160.0, 40.0); // set your own position
    // give button tag to remove and add to self.view

    button1.tag = 1001;
    [self.view addSubview:button1];
    [controller.view  bringSubviewToFront:button1];

    [player pause];
    [player play];


}
-(void)backMethod
{
    controller.view.hidden=YES;
    [player pause];
     // remove back button when hide
    [[self.view viewWithTag:1001] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: thanks a ton. It worked for me. I have one more question as I play the video it is in portrait mode, but I want when I click the play button it should directly play it in landscape mode.

Comment: It's giving me the following error : Property 'videoGravity' not found on object of type 'AVPlayer *'

Comment: Sorry `controller.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;`

Comment: I tried that also but it does not work. Anyways thank u so much.

Comment: you need to use  `AVPlayerViewController`  with previous solution to allow full screen , need some tricks